# SVN Eclipse Subversive plugin and local repository

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I need to learn SVN plugin Eclipse  Subversive.

I want to use my file system to fake a real repository server.

So I used something like this on my terminal (using windows) :
"svnadmin create repository"

It created a repository. Now when using Eclipse, I'm trying to define with Subversive plugin a repository server (I want to use the repository "repository" I just created) :

[image]

But when I validate I got this error message :
SVN: '0x00400006: Validate Repository Location' operation finished with error: Selected SVN connector library is not available or cannot be loaded.
If you selected native JavaHL connector, please check if binaries are available or install and select pure Java Subversion connector from the plug-in connectors update site.
If connectors already installed then you can change the selected one at: Window->Preferences->Team->SVN->SVN Connector.

Comment: Why not use your FS to make up a real repository server? Use git or hg or something like that. Specifically about eclipse, I don't know if it comes with hg plugins but I think it includes egit for git.

Comment: It seems you missed to [install an SVN connector](https://www.eclipse.org/subversive/installation-instructions.php#phase2) (also in the _SVN Repositories_ view the _New Repository_ icon is disabled). In _Window > Preferences: Team > SVN_, in tab _SVN Connector_ what is selected for _SVN Connector_?